# Filtering multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to filter multiple columns using this formula:

```
=OR(A:A="Text", B:B="Text")
```

[https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-filter-multiple-columns/#:~:text=Step%202%3A%20Apply%20Filter%20to%20Multiple%20Columns&text=To%20do%20so%2C%20click%20cell,What%20is%20this%3F&text=Next%2C%20click%20the%20Filter%20icon,then%20click%20Filter%20by%20condition](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-filter-multiple-columns/#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Apply%20Filter%20to%20Multiple%20Columns&text=To%20do%20so%2C%20click%20cell,What%20is%20this%3F&text=Next%2C%20click%20the%20Filter%20icon,then%20click%20Filter%20by%20condition).

How can I add more things to filter here? e.g.

```
=OR(A:A="Text 1","Text 2", B:B="Text 1", "Text 2")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know your end goal, your data, data types, international locale, sheet setup, ranges... really nothing. So while your generic example makes sense to you (who backed that example out of full knowledge of your spreadsheet), it doesn't tell those of us "out here" very much. What it *does* show is that you aren't using the `OR` function correctly (and likely would not use `OR` at all in what you're trying to do anyway). Please share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), so that we can see the problem in context.

Comment: In that spreadsheet, hand-enter a few examples of what you want a formula to return. Off to the side in some empty cells, explain how you determined what those results should be. Then the volunteer contributors here will have enough to begin offering suggested approaches for formulas that will return those results.

Comment: THANKS SOOO MUCH Oren Pinsky

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`=OR(A:A="Text 1",A:A="Text 2", B:B="Text 1", B:B="Text 2")`